# Bug? Nested CSS vendor prefix breaks Chrome CSS parsing

Tags: css, google-chrome, vendor-prefix

CSS nesting is a relatively new feature that is now natively supported in all major browsers. Please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_nesting/Using_CSS_nesting for more information on CSS nesting.

In the following example, the "This Button Should Be Red" button should be red. It's red in FireFox, but in Chrome it is not. My Chrome version is `119.0.6045.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)`.

Only if I remove the `&::-moz-focus-inner { ... }` rule will Chrome display it correctly as red.

Is this a bug in Chrome?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>CSS Nesting Test</title>
    <style>
        button {
            &::-moz-focus-inner {
                border-width: 0;
            }

            &:not(:disabled) {
                background-color: red;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:50px;">
<button>This Button Should Be Red</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"If a nested CSS rule is invalid then all of the enclosed styles will be ignored. This does not affect the parent or preceding rules."* `-moz-focus-inner` is [not listed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) as valid pseudo element, hence Chrome treats it as invalid selector. If you need rules for only one vendor, just put them last. If several vendors are necessary, I don't see any obvious workaround except for defining every vendor in separate parent rules (one group per vendor).

Comment: @STerliakov awesome, that solves it then. post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Yes it is a Chrome bug. The button background should be red in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per nesting [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_nesting/Using_CSS_nesting#invalid_nested_style_rules),

> If a nested CSS rule is invalid then all of the enclosed styles will be ignored. This does not affect the parent or preceding rules.

`::-moz-focus-inner` is [not listed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) as a valid pseudo element, hence Chrome treats it as invalid selector.

If you need rules for only one vendor, you can just put them last. If several vendors are necessary, I don't see any obvious workaround except for defining every vendor in separate parent rule (one group per vendor).

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>CSS Nesting Test</title>
    <style>
        button {
            &:not(:disabled) {
                background-color: red;
            }

            &::-moz-focus-inner {
                border-width: 0;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:50px;">
<button>This Button Should Be Red</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmm, the example at the first link you provide clearly shows that rules following a rule with an invalid selector should "work fine", and preceding prose says that "The rule that includes this selector is ignored, but **subsequent valid rules are not**". Furthermore placing an invalid rule at the same place in Firefox does not stop the button background from being red. So I think it;s a Chrome bug.

Comment: @Alohci hm, I did not pay sufficient attention. This really looks like the following selectors should not be invalidated. Pobably Chrome devs read this paragraph in the same way I did initially...